# Extract Source Code from APK

Tags: java, android, apk

I need to extract source code from an apk file. I am aware about the apktool and have used it many times. Problem with that approach is extracted code changes a little bit and all the resource loading has static value, like loading a layout. I have got the res folder as well, but i can not determine which layout to load where.

I need reliable solution that extracts complete source code with generated R as well. I think it is possible.

Comment: Just ask the developer for the source code or download it if it's open source.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is possibly about violating application licensing terms and conditions.

Comment: Hello Simon,
I appreciate your concerns for licensing terms and conditions.For your information, It is my application. I have lost the the source code and left with only apk file.

Comment: `I am aware about the apktool and have used it many times`.  This suggests that you have lost a lot of your source code or, you are regularly violating application licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to do this the way you want.

Here is the reason: `.apk` is a final artifact in chain: *java source (`.java`) > java bytecode (`.class`) > dalvik bytecode (`.dex`) > application package (`.apk`)*

You do can extract `.dex` from `.apk` without loss (similar to extracting `.class` from `.jar`, because `.jar` is simply zip archive), but this won't help you to get the **same exact** sources because compilation from `.java` to `.class` and then to `.dex` is not reversible (in general case).

**UPDATE**: even modern decompilation tools for java bytecode (like jad) sometimes fail to produce valid sources for bytecode (happened with me couple of times), not to mention dalvik bytecode that is even more "twisted" by compilation process.